# why do you need Log4Net for nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, log4net, elmah

I am going to build my application using asp.net mvc3 and nhibernate 3.2. I decided to use Elmah to log all the error messages.

I remember nhibernate supports log4net and use it to log all queries.  If I dont care about outputting the queries to the log file, I can use nhibernate profiler to do that, what other reasons will stop me swtiching from log4net to Elmah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, whether you actively use the logging abilities of NHibernate or not, the NHibernate library's code has dependencies on log4net, and so you will need to have the log4net DLL available to NHibernate in order to load the NHibernate DLL. You can only get around this by downloading the NHibernate source and modifying it to remove uses of log4net (either stripping out the logging capability entirely or replacing it with Elmah).

This is why, in general, you must be careful what libraries you use to develop your own code, because the more you use, the more your app will need, even if the user never actually causes your app to execute a single line of the referenced code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess I will leave log4net dll there, just not doing anything with it.  By the way, I removed all log4net settings from web.config file. is it ok?

Comment: I want to say yes, because log4net should be robust enough to know what to do without error if it doesn't have a configuration, but I would do a thorough test of the entire system to make sure.

Comment: This answer is not correct; NHibernate has removed hard dependencies on log4net. Sly's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

In NHibernate 3+ tight dependency on log4net is broken. You can easily use it with nlog for [example](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/using-nlog-via-common-logging-with-nhibernate.html).