# Why log4net used in nhibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

What is the purpose of using log4net in NHibernate. As I am a beginner in MVC and NHibernate, so kindly try to solve my basics.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why do you need Log4Net for nhibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932425/why-do-you-need-log4net-for-nhibernate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate uses HQL to leverage its expressiveness to the developer, but behind the scenes there is an engine that transforms the HQL into pure SQL that is executed against the database.

> Log4net helps to see what SQL Statements, NHibernate is generating
>   under the covers.

Comment: Thanks Min Min its really helpful to me...Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [official site](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/):

> The Apache log4net library is a tool to help the programmer output log
>   statements to a variety of output targets.

To put it in layman words, it provides methods to log debug information (automatically or manually generated) to a database/xml file/text file etc.

There is a good guide on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net) for learning it.

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for a great support.