# Problem with log4net dll versions when executing my program

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, dll, log4net

I'm having a problem with the log4net dll. I downloaded a project from TFS and suddenly i had problems when building the web project. I didn't have the 2.0.8 version of the log4net dll. Then, I updated the version using NuGet and I managed to build and start the project. I can reach the login page as shown below:

[image]

But, after i fill the fields and then click the "Entra" button the system shows me this error.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why do you need Log4Net for nhibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932425/why-do-you-need-log4net-for-nhibernate).  Basically it looks like you have two 3rd party Nuget packages each fighting over which log4net to use.  Non-strong-named assemblies can only be loaded once per AppDomain irrespective of version.  You could get around it by using child AppDomains OR removing all Nuget packages and adding an explicit reference to log4net first; then adding the other Nuget packages that depend on log4net

Comment: It's the first time that i need to use this code for developing since i worked on other projects. Unfortunately i don't know why we need Log4Net and i'm only trying to resolve this problems to work on this code. What do you suggest then?

Comment: You can remove log4net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day i solved the problem. It was connected with another dll updated and added by me. Adding the dll not by Visual Studio but updating it directly in the bin folder solved it.

Now all works.

Comment: _"Adding the dll not by Visual Studio but updating it directly in the bin folder"_ - that's not the way to do things.  Are you going to do that for each nightly build?

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot solved this problem in any other way. The project is heavily bugged and the only way to fix this type of problem is to recreate the entire web site. I need to do some bug fixing and i need to be fast as requested by the customer.